# How to resolve internal imports in lambda function

Tags: python, python-3.x, amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, aws-cloudformation

I have a project with structure like this:

```
.
├── README.md
└── src/
    ├── some_package_1/
    |   ├── setup.py
    |   └── some_module_1/
    |       ├── __init__.py
    |       ├── some_module_1.py
    ├── some_package_2/
    |   ├── setup.py
    |   └── some_module_2/
    |       ├── __init__.py
    |       ├── some_module_2.py
    ├── some_lambda/
    |   ├── lambda_function.py
    |   └── cfn-templates
    |       ├── my_template.yml
```

My lambda_function.py looks like this:

```
from src.some_package_1.some_module_1 import some_module_1
from src.some_package_2.some_module_2 import some_module_2

def lambda_handler(event, context):
    # Ofc logic here is simplified
    some_module_1()
    some_module_2()
```

My question is: How to import things located in parent directory to lambda function?

What I tried: Following [this](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/lambda/latest/dg/python-package-create.html#python-package-create-with-dependency) tutorial to make zip archive for my dependencies, however this lambda func will be deployed using CloudFormation template, and I don't know how to implement steps of installing my packages in one directory and zipping it, within CloudFormation template.

Is there any standard for handling imports like this with lambda functions?

Comment: What about using SAM?

Comment: @Marcin All the examples on the SAM examples github https://github.com/amazon-archives/serverless-app-examples seems not to cover my use case. I have private packages in my repository and wonder how to resolve them in my template. Could you please give me additional info on where to start? I should add that I am new to working with AWS in general. Should i specify `some_module_1` in requirements.txt, or `sam build` should recognize the imports by itself

Comment: How did it go? Did package work?

Comment: @Marcin Partially yes, i had to wrote shell script to install my other modules to the `some_lambda/` dir and then package it and deploy. Thanks :)

Comment: glad it worked. If so, acceptance of the answer would be appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

CloudFormation does support automated creating of zip packages for lambda as explained in:

- [Uploading local artifacts to an S3 bucket](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSCloudFormation/latest/UserGuide/using-cfn-cli-package.html)

For that you have to use [aws cloudformation package](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cli/latest/reference/cloudformation/package.html) command.

Comment: That looks promising. Thanks a lot :)

Comment: @w8eight No problem. Please let me know how it will go.